# Homorphism theorem for free product of groups in Massey

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm a little confused on what Proposition 2.2 of Massey's Algebraic Topology: An Introduction is saying; I first rewrote the theorems below and then after my issues are summarized:

> Theorem 2.1:
>   If $\{G_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a collection of abelian groups, then for any abelian group $A$ and any collection
>   of homomorphisms $\psi_i:G_i \to A$ there exists a unique homomorphism $f:G\to A$ such that for any $i\in I$ the following diagram is commutative
>
> $$\varphi_i : G_i \to G$$
>   $$\psi_i:G_i\to A$$
>   $$f:G\to A$$
>   (I don't know how to draw this diagram... help if you don't mind)
>
> Proposition 2.2:
>   Let $\{G_i\},G$ and $\varphi_i:G_i \to G$ be as in Theorem 2.1; let $G'$ be any abelian group and 
>   let $\varphi_i':G_i \to G'$ be any collection of homomorphisms such that the conclusion of Theorem 2.1 holds with $G'$ and $\varphi_i'$
>   substituded for $G$ and $\varphi_i$ respectively.  Then, there exists a unique isomorphism $h:G\to G'$ such that the following diagram is commutative for any $i\in I$
>
> $$\varphi_i : G_i \to G$$
>   $$\varphi'_i:G_i\to G'$$
>   $$h:G\to G'$$

1) My first issue is that Prop 2.2 says let $\varphi_i$ be any collection of homomorphisms such that the conclusion of Theorem 2.1 holds.  Isn't that any homomorphism from $G_i$ to $G'$... that was the point of Theorem 2.1, right?  We get the existence of a unique $f:G\to A$ that makes the diagram commute regardless of what $\varphi_i$ are.

2) I'm confused by the "substituded for $G$ and $\varphi_i$" part. Maybe this is a matter of just having the theorem rephrased, it isn't clicking....  maybe item 1 is me not understanding the "substituded for $G$ and $\varphi_i$" part correctly?

Answer (score 1):

As for the commutative diagram, I'm having a hard time typing it here on stackexchange, but it would look like this: $$\begin{array}{ccc}
G_i & \xrightarrow{\phi_i} & G \\ &\searrow{\psi_i} & \downarrow{f}\\ & & A
\end{array}$$

To answer your questions, another way to view the proposition that may be more intuitive is the following:
If another abelian group $G'$ and an associated family of group homomorphisms $\phi_i'$ satisfy all the same properties as $G$ and $\phi_i$ in the theorem, then $G$ and $G'$ are isomorphic. That is, the properties in the theorem specify the abelian group $G$ (which is called a coproduct in the category of abelian groups) uniquely up to isomorphism.